# Check for multiplicity of a float object

Tags: python, types

I'm very new to python coding and trying to write some simple calculating scripts. Here's where I'm stuck. I need to check multiplicity of my `angle` variable, but the solution I've come up with doesn't work (afaik `%` never returns zero for `float` objects). My code:

```
angle = 2.1
number_of_rotations = 1  # Each rotation adds another 2.1 to the angle

while angle % 5 != 0: 
    angle += 2.1 # I want my angle variable to become something like 210.0 (which multiples five) and then to be returned as an output
    number_of_rotations += 1
print('Angle:', angle, 'Number of rotations:', number_of_rotations)
```

Questions:

1. How do I convert `float` into `int` so that I don't lose decimal part and check multiplicity?
2. My interpreter returns amusingly large numbers, e.g. 4934475.0 for `angle` variable. I'm wondering why does it stop exactly on this number and doesn't drop an error?

Comment: “How do I convert float into int so that I don't lose decimal part” - I’d recommend doing some research to obtain a better understanding of `float` and `int` values.

Comment: Additionally, try `210.0 % 5 == 0`, or `if not 210.0 % 5` These will validate to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I convert float into int so that I don't lose decimal part and check multiplicity?**

→ Use `int(your_variable)`. It's easy :). But you will loose the decimal part... Here is the solution:

Sometimes, Python doesn't calculate very accurately (in fact, it's a bit harder. watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNhSbvG24jQ)). In your case, `angle` variable will take for example `10773.000000001031` instead of `10773.0`. As you can see, Python add some decimals, which make your condition false. To prevent this behaviour, you can round your variable to have always 1 decimal number. Do it like that:

```py
angle = 2.1
number_of_rotations = 1  # Each rotation adds another 2.1 to the angle

while angle % 5 != 0: 
    angle += 2.1 # I want my angle variable to become something like 210.0 (which multiples five) and then to be returned as an output
    angle = round(angle, 1) # round your variable
    number_of_rotations += 1
print('Angle:', angle, 'Number of rotations:', number_of_rotations)
```

It prints `Angle: 105.0 Number of rotations: 50`

---

**How I found that?**

Since you are a beginner, I will tell you how to debug your program. It's easy: just add a `print` instruction in your loop. Like that:

```py
while angle % 5 != 0: 
    ...
    print(angle)
    ...
```

and then you will see that `angle` does not take what you expected.

---

**EDIT:**

For more flexibility, you can use this script:

```py
angle = 2.1
number_of_rotations = 1  # Each rotation adds another 2.1 to the angle

while angle % 5 != 0: 
    angle += 2.1 # I want my angle variable to become something like 210.0 (which multiples five) and then to be returned as an output
    angle = round(angle, str(angle)[::-1].find('.')) # round your variable
    number_of_rotations += 1
print('Angle:', angle, 'Number of rotations:', number_of_rotations)
```

`str(angle)[::-1].find('.')` return the number of decimal place in `angle`. Thus, if you change `angle` to `32.20192` for example, the variable will be rounded perfectly.

Comment: I disagree with the statement ‘it’s easy'.  In fact, it’s impossible.  By mathematical definition, a integer is a whole number; therefore the decimal (fractional) portion of a number will *always* be lost.  Additionally, this statement is inaccurate: “Python doesn't calculate very accurately”.  Please do some more research on floating point calculations.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked! Btw if I use `int(var)`,  don't I lose my decimal part? EDIT: didn't see the answer above

Comment: @S3DEV, yes I saw my mistake but I forgot to correct before to post... I just edited my answer... For the point of "Python doesn't calculate very accurately", I formulated it in a easier way I think. I will add an article about that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,
you should round your answer..
angle = 2.1
number_of_rotations = 1  # Each rotation adds another 2.1 to the angle

```
while angle % 5 != 0:
    angle += 2.1 # I want my angle variable to become something like 210.0 (which multiples five) and then to be returned as an output
    number_of_rotations += 1
    angle=round(angle,2)
print('Angle:', angle, 'Number of rotations:', number_of_rotations)
```